# Unpack DataFrame with tuple entries into separate DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, iterable-unpacking

I wrote a small class to compute some statistics through [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) without replacement. For those not familiar with this technique, you get `n` random subsamples of some data, compute the desired statistic (lets say the median) on each subsample, and then compare the values across subsamples. This allows you to get a measure of variance on the obtained median over the dataset.

I implemented this in a class but reduced it to a MWE given by the following function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def bootstrap_median(df, n=5000, fraction=0.1):
    if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        columns = df.columns
    else:
        columns = None
    # Get the values as a ndarray
    arr = np.array(df.values)

    # Get the bootstrap sample through random permutations
    sample_len = int(len(arr)*fraction)
    if sample_len<1:
        sample_len = 1
    sample = []
    for n_sample in range(n):
        sample.append(arr[np.random.permutation(len(arr))[:sample_len]])
    sample = np.array(sample)

    # Compute the median on each sample
    temp = np.median(sample, axis=1)

    # Get the mean and std of the estimate across samples
    m = np.mean(temp, axis=0)
    s = np.std(temp, axis=0)/np.sqrt(len(sample))

    # Convert output to DataFrames if necesary and return
    if columns:
        m = pd.DataFrame(data=m[None, ...], columns=columns)
        s = pd.DataFrame(data=s[None, ...], columns=columns)
    return m, s
```

This function returns the mean and standard deviation across the medians computed on each bootstrap sample.

Now consider this example `DataFrame`

```
data  = np.arange(20)
group = np.tile(np.array([1, 2]).reshape(-1,1), (1,10)).flatten()
df    = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'data': data, 'group': group})
print(df)
print(bootstrap_median(df['data']))
```

this prints

```
    data  group
0      0      1
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      1
4      4      1
5      5      1
6      6      1
7      7      1
8      8      1
9      9      1
10    10      2
11    11      2
12    12      2
13    13      2
14    14      2
15    15      2
16    16      2
17    17      2
18    18      2
19    19      2

(9.5161999999999995, 0.056585753613431718)
```

So far so good because `bootstrap_median` returns a `tuple` of two elements. However, if I do this after a `groupby`

```
In: df.groupby('group')['data'].apply(bootstrap_median)

Out:
group
1     (4.5356, 0.0409710449952)
2    (14.5006, 0.0403772204095)
```

The values inside each cell are `tuple`s, as one would expect from `apply`. I can unpack the result into two `DataFrame`'s by iterating over elements like this:

```
index = []
data1 = []
data2 = []
for g, (m, s) in out.iteritems():
    index.append(g)
    data1.append(m)
    data2.append(s)
dfm = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, index=index, columns=['E[median]'])
dfm.index.name = 'group'
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, index=index, columns=['std[median]'])
dfs.index.name = 'group'
```

thus

```
In: dfm
Out:
       E[median]
group  
1         4.5356
2        14.5006

In: dfs
Out:
           std[median]
group  
1      0.0409710449952
2      0.0403772204095
```

This is a bit cumbersome and my question is if there is a more `pandas` native way to "unpack" a dataframe whose values are tuples into separate `DataFrame`'s

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729551/pandas-dataframe-cell-label-value-split-into-2-separate-dataframes) seemed related but it concerned string regex replacements and not unpacking true tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need change:

```
return m, s
```

to:

```
return pd.Series([m, s], index=['m','s'])
```

And then get:

```
df1 = df.groupby('group')['data'].apply(bootstrap_median)
print (df1)
group   
1      m     4.480400
       s     0.040542
2      m    14.565200
       s     0.040373
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

So is possible select by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df1.xs('s', level=1))
group
1    0.040542
2    0.040373
Name: data, dtype: float64

print (df1.xs('m', level=1))
group
1     4.4804
2    14.5652
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

Also if need one column `DataFrame` add [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('group')['data'].apply(bootstrap_median).to_frame()
print (df1)
              data
group             
1     m   4.476800
      s   0.041100
2     m  14.468400
      s   0.040719

print (df1.xs('s', level=1))
           data
group          
1      0.041100
2      0.040719

print (df1.xs('m', level=1))
          data
group         
1       4.4768
2      14.4684
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion! By returning a `pandas.Series` I just side step the problem of having to unpack tuples, and stay inside the `pandas` framework. I'll wait a bit more to see if any other answer comes in that talks about unpacking tuples, and if none arrive, I'll accept yours.